# Which scripting language interpreters does JDK contain?

Tags: java, jvm

Some time ago I read about [JavaTM Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html), but I could not find information about which language-interpreters (excepting JS) Oracle JVM implements. Where can I find a full list? Or does the JVM not interpret anything but JavaScript by default?

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); // what else?
```

Comment: `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` has methods to look up what scripting engines are available. Look it up in the API documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you know most of what I'm about to say, but lest someone else stumble upon this who doesn't:

Javascript is included by default, as it was the reference implementation (Rhino).  It's not quite right to consider it "embedded" - the implementation just happens to be bundled as a reference implementation for JSR-223.  As far as I'm aware, it's no different than any other implementation, except that it happens to exist by default.

However, implementations exist for MANY other languages, aren't JVM/JDK specific (just requiring Java 6 or better) and are fairly trivial to add in an application.

I've used Perl, Groovy, Haskell, Javascript, and Python and a few others (doing some performance testing, related to possibly using it as a solution).

There are a lot of available languages if you want to install them: 
https://confluence.deri.ie:8443/display/romulus/JSR+223+compliant+scripting+languages

Comment: Thank you a lot for answer and especially for link! +1

Answer (score 2):

I found answer with @Jesper assistance. `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` has method [`getEngineFactories()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html#getEngineFactories%28%29) which returns...

> ...a list whose elements are instances of all the ScriptEngineFactory classes found by the discovery mechanism.

I wrote this code snippet to get list of supported engines:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
for (ScriptEngineFactory sef : factory.getEngineFactories()) {
    System.out.println(sef.getEngineName() + " (" + sef.getLanguageName() + ")");
}
```

*Output:*

> Mozilla Rhino (ECMAScript)

[Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) is an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely in Java.

### Conclusion:

Oracle JDK has only one embedded script-language interpreter - JS interpreter.